# Who called the event / observer in magento?

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

Eg I have a `block` that is on the `page` to edit the purchase order, both the editing page of the order as the "block" passes through the event `sales_order_load_after` when obeserver the event can not know what they spent for the event, if it was `page` or `block`.

How to know who called or went by event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a PHP backtrace function like `debug_backtrace` or Magento's own backtrace: `mageDebugBacktrace`.